# MSB3073 The command "gradlew.bat -p "C:\Users\jason\source\repos\Android1\Android1\app" assemblex86-64Debug" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio

So this is my first time creating an APP on my new PC which is Windows 11. I used Visual Studio 2022 V 17.6 straight out of the box. It updated loads of things and installed that and that. I click File/New Project and select Basic Application (Andriod, Gradle), click next. Gave my project a name ‘Apt-booking’ and solution box I enter ‘Apt-booking-solution’. All good so far. I click Build menu and select Build solution, and get the error…

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3073 The command “gradlew.bat -p “C:\Users\jason\source\repos\Android1\Android1\app” assemblex86-64Debug” exited with code 1. Android1 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V150\Android.Common.targets 546

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: That error is the result of another error. You need to provide a longer part of the output window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in the command prompt:

```
gradlew.bat -p “C:\Users\jason\...
```

This bat-file is placed in your project directory, so you'll get full error message there.

In my case, `Gradle` can't download and install itself and some errors more.